# Method PATCH is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, jetty

I'm not 100% sure where the error is coming from but I think it has something todo with my nginx configuration file. I'm trying todo a PATCH request from my Angularjs application using restangular and when I try doing this on my production server I get the following error from the developer tools in console

```
PATCH https://localhost:9000/api/v1/projects/12 501 (Method PATCH is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API)
```

From what I have read so far nginx does not allow PATCH requests by default, is this true and if this is true how do you allow this method type?

The errors.log for nginx is empty but in my **access.log** I have the below, which tells me nothing went wrong with nginx and its something else?

```
0.0.0.10 - - [11/Nov/2015:09:09:16 +0000] "PATCH /api/v1/projects/12 HTTP/1.1" 501 0 "https://0.0.0.1/ss/projects" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Can anyone confirm if this is an nginx issue or something else and what can I try to fix it. Below are the `location(s)` I have in my nginx.conf file, please let me know if you need to see something else:

```
location / {
  default_type text/plain;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/ss/dist/;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /api {
  client_max_body_size 1000m;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/api;
  proxy_read_timeout 360s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So turns out it was Jetty causing the issue as Jetty does not accept PATCH HTTP methods - [Jetty Docs](http://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/9.2.9.v20150224/apidocs/?d)